# Starting TensorBoard b'54' at http://ASUS-PC:6006

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

```
tensorboard --logdir=-logs
Starting TensorBoard b'54' at http://ASUS-PC:6006
(Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I try to use tensorboard, connecting http://ASUS-PC:6006 or http://localhost:6006, but I can't see anything. How can I fix it? I use pycharm. Sorry I don't have enough reputation in it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.